# ValueError: too many values to unpack python

Tags: python, unpack

```
s = ('con', 'str', 'wit', 'int', 'dex', 'mp', 'p.def', 'm.def', 'p.atack', 'm.atack') 
c.execute("SELECT con, str, wit, _int, dex, mp, mdef, pdef, patack, matack FROM warrior_stat")
t = c.fetchone()[:]
for s1, t1 in s, t: print "%020s, " - ", %010s, '\n'" % (s, t)
```

Why do I have this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 49, in <module>
    for s1, t1 in s, t: print "%020s, " - ", %010s, '\n'" % (s, t)
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

How can I fix it?

thanks for all comments !!! i am printing 
    %(s, t) instead (s1, t1)
and 
    zip(s, t) 
worked correctly after this corection

dont make +1 into reputation. but my reputation is low

Comment: Maybe you want to use the `zip` function like that: `for z1,t1 in zip(s, t): ...`

Comment: Try this: `for s1, t1 in s, t: print "%020s, " - ", %010s, '\n'" % (s1, t1)` Isn't that what you wanted to print?

Comment: for s1, t1 in zip(s, t): print "%020s, " - ", %010s, '\n'" % (s, t)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
i am wanna view finally:                                                            `code` con - 3000' `code` 'str - 300' etc...

Comment: @KobiK Subtracting strings is unlikely to work.

Comment: thanks for all comments !!! i am printing 
    %(s, t) instead (s1, t1)
and 
    zip(s, t) 
worked correctly after this corection

Answer (score 2):

I think there should be single quotes inside

```
print "%020s, " - ", %010s, '\n'" % (s, t)
```

In this case only second part of string is formatted

```
", %010s, '\n'" % (s, t)
```

And here as You can see only one place holder for value but 2 value is passed
So this is incorrect.

and I don't know why `\n` is quoted.
It seems that this line should be following:

```
print "%020s -  %010s, \n" % (s, t)
```

Comment: ", %010s, '\n'" % (s, t) the same error: ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: Yes this is the same issue :( I just wanted to explain where it is

Answer (score 0):

you need to zip two lists, and it should be in one string:

```
for s1, t1 in zip(s, t):
    print "%020s - %010s \n" % (s, t)
```

Comment: if used zip(s, t) - TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: the error was caused by the fact, that you had separate strings, when you put everything in one it should work. i corrected my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

To be strict, your 2nd problem would probable be worth opening another question, because now you have a problem elsewhere.

With

```
print "%020s, " - ", %010s, '\n'" % (s, t)
```

you apply the `%` operation to `", %010s, '\n'"`, which is clearly not correct.

Even if it was, you'd get another error: you try to subtract the resulting string from `"%020s, "` which doesn't work as well.

Try

```
print "%020s - %010s" % (s, t)
```

Comment: for s1, t1 in zip(s, t): print "%020s - %010s, \n" % (s1, t1) #worked